# JLabel's tooltip text disabling its parent JPanel mouseEnter event

Tags: java, mouseevent

Why does the tooltip event of `JLabel` disabling its JPanel's mouseEnter event? 
This does not happen if JLabel has no tooltip text set.

*How can I keep the mouseEnter event even while hovering over JLabel ?*

**Normal state, mouse is not over JPanel**
[image]

**Hover state, mouse is over JPanel, it changes color to red**
[image]

**Hover state, mouse is over JLabel, which is inside JPanel**

Background should be red.
[image]

**Code:**

```
public class MyJFrame extends JFrame {

    private final Color default_color = Color.orange;
    private final Color hover_color = Color.red;

    private JLabel jLabel1;
    private JPanel jPanel1;

    public MyJFrame() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        jPanel1 = new JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        jPanel1.setBackground(default_color);
        jPanel1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
                jPanel1.setBackground(hover_color);
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) {
                jPanel1.setBackground(default_color);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.setLayout(null);
        jLabel1.setText("?");
        jLabel1.setToolTipText("This label's tooltip text disabling mouseEnter event.");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel1);
        jLabel1.setBounds(313, 0, 27, 30);

        getContentPane().add(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setBounds(30, 40, 340, 30);

        pack();
    }                                                                
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? Having the same problem :)